# Routing Error "No route matches" 'new' path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `User` model and a `Storefront` model.

#### For some reason, when I try to go to /storefronts/new I get this error:

> Routing Error
>   No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"storefronts",
>   :id=># Storefront id: nil, name: nil, user_id: 4, created_at: nil,
>   updated_at: nil, description: nil, location: nil>}

Been at it for 3 hours trying to figure this out. It was working yesterday..
Why does it say **:action=>"edit"** when its the 'new' action?

Here's my code:

```
class Storefront < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :location, :description
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_one :storefront
end

class StorefrontsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_auth, only: [:new, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @storefronts = Storefront.all
  end

  def new
    @storefront = current_user.build_storefront
  end

  def create
    @storefront = current_user.build_storefront(params[:storefront])
    if @storefront.save
      redirect_to edit_storefront_path(@storefront)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

def show
    @storefront = Storefront.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @storefront = Storefront.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @storefront = Storefront.find(params[:id])
    if @storefront.update_attributes(params[:storefront])
      redirect_to @storefront
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end


Pbf::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :sessions, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :users
  resources :storefronts

  root :to => 'storefronts#index'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
end
```

Link I'm using **(Here's the issue)**:

```
  <% if current_user.storefront %>
    <%= link_to "Manage Storefront", edit_storefront_path(current_user.storefront) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Open Storefront!", openstore_path %>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
My `rake routes`

> ```
>    sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)             sessions#create
> new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)         sessions#new
>     session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)         sessions#destroy
>       users GET    /users(.:format)                users#index
>             POST   /users(.:format)                users#create
>    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)            users#new
>   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)       users#edit
>        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show
>             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)            users#update
>             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)            users#destroy
> storefronts GET    /storefronts(.:format)          storefronts#index
>             POST   /storefronts(.:format)          storefronts#create  
> new_storefront GET    /storefronts/new(.:format)   storefronts#new 
> edit_storefront GET    /storefronts/:id/edit(.:format) storefronts#edit
>  storefront GET    /storefronts/:id(.:format)      storefronts#show
>             PUT    /storefronts/:id(.:format)      storefronts#update
>             DELETE /storefronts/:id(.:format)      storefronts#destroy
> ```

Comment: Look at the output of `rake routes` for any obvious clues related to this path.

Comment: I'll edit in my `rake routes`

Comment: What line in your template is that error on?  And, what action is being hit when you look in your logs?  Just ensuring you're hitting the new action as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you have an error in your view. `app/views/storefronts/new.html.erb` is mistakenly referencing `edit_storefront_path` without passing `storefront_id` as a parameter. You probably want `storefronts_path`

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I get the same error even if I erase everything in my `app/views/storefronts/new.html.erb` file. I did a project-wide search for storefront_path and it only pops up 3 times (edit_storefront_path twice and new_storefront_path once)

Comment: Edited above. Are any of those 2 occurrences of `edit_storefront_path` being referenced in this view? One of them isn't getting a valid storefront.

Comment: Yes! That was the problem. I edited my question to show it, but I basically had a conditional that put an invalid `edit_storefront_path` in there. I should just throw the logic in a helper? Forgive me for being dense, but could you explain why having an invaid `edit_storefront_path` in the view messes up the `new_storefront_path` link?

Comment: The problem is that this your conditional, `current_user.storefront` is testing for the storefront object, which exists because you've built it in your controller, but it hasn't been saved yet, so it's id is `nil`. When you call `edit_storefront_path(current_user.storefront)` the `edit_storefront_path` helper is looking for an object with a non-nil id. The error message is telling you exactly that in this bit ` :id=># Storefront id: nil`

Answer (score 0):

It's `new_storefronts_path` it's collection route,If you pass singular form then it's consider as member route if you haven't declare any named route,
that's why route is picking to edit action and regarding id 4 is you are  not passing id as per convention so `nil.object_id` is 4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this: `match '/openstore', to: 'storefronts#new'` with `<%= link_to "New Storefront", openstore_path %>` but I'm still getting the exact same error. What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is router can't figure out 'new' from some kind of ':id'. Try to add constraint to your edit route declaration

```
get 'storefronts/:id/edit' => 'storefronts#edit', :id => /[\d]*/
```

Then only digital id will be interpreted as a call for edit action.